# PHP: How to add a variable to a function name?

Tags: php, function, variables

I have a class with a callback.  I pass a string to the class and the callback gets called with that string as the callback function.  It works a little like this:

```
$obj->runafter( 'do_this' );

function do_this( $args ) {
    echo 'done';
}
```

What I am looking to do is run this inside of a loop and so that the function doesn't get written multiple times I want to add a variable to the function name.  What I want to do is something like this:

```
for( $i=0;$i<=3;$i++ ) :
    $obj->runafter( 'do_this_' . $i );

    function do_this_{$i}( $args ) {
        echo 'done';
    }
endfor;
```

Any ideas on how I can accomplish this in PHP?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would pass the function in directly as a closure:

```
for($i=0; $i<=3; $i++) {
    $obj->runafter(function($args) use($i) {
        echo "$i is done";
    });
}
```

Note how you can `use($i)` to make this local variable available in your callback if needed.

Here is a working example: https://3v4l.org/QV66p

More info on callables and closures:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php

Comment: Appreciated, that's actually madness x) Nice one!

Comment: @KyleE4K just updated with a working example link as well

Comment: I wonder if this is possible with C# (more strongly typed languages) - research time haha

Comment: @KyleE4K of course it is possible. In C# you can use Delegate

Comment: @KyleE4K ready to really have your mind blown? in PHP 7 you can create anonymous classes on the fly as well! http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.anonymous.php

Comment: I've made numerous forums, portals and CMS's and never once come across Closures. You don't understand how much time these will save! & :O but using this will be so much faster, how can we upgrade to PHP 7? - Tbh, thats alot like more strongly typed languages

Comment: Worked perfectly!  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can assign function to variable and create closure also you can pass variable outside the scope of anonymous function via use keyword

```
$callback = function($args) use($i) {
    echo "$i is done";
};

for ($i = 0; $i <= 3; $i++) {
    $arg = "some argument";
    $obj->runafter($callback($arg));
}
```

Useful links:

- http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/class.closure.php

Comment: Upvoted for showing how you can define the function as a closure first. Note you need a semi-colon at the end of the function definition, and you'll get `Notice: Undefined variable: i`. If notices are turned on.

Answer (score 0):

According to your question, you should define your function before the loop. Then you don't have to worry about it being redefined on each loop iteration.

```
function do_this( $args ) {
    echo 'done';
}

for( $i=0;$i<=3;$i++ ) :
    $obj->runafter( 'do_this' );
endfor;
```